# how to handle spaces in file path if the folder contains the space?

Tags: c#, .net, file-io, console-application

```
public static void launchProcess(string processName, string arguments, out string output)
{
    Process p = new Process
    {
        StartInfo = { UseShellExecute = false, RedirectStandardOutput = true, FileName = processName, Arguments = arguments }
    };

    p.Start();
    output = p.StandardOutput.ReadToEnd();
    p.WaitForExit();

}
```

And if my arguments contains the file names like:

```
D:\Visual Studio Projects\ProjectOnTFS\ProjectOnTFS
```

Then I get the error:

Comment: What is the error that you are calling "the error?"

Comment: Use double-quotes like `"D:\Visual Studio Projects\ProjectOnTFS\ProjectOnTFS"` for arguments.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

It'll need doubles quotes, but will also likely need an @ to treat the string word-for-word ([verbatim string](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa691090%28v=vs.71%29.aspx)) i.e. the "\" has a special meaning in string e.g. \t means a tab, so we want to ignore the \

So not only the double quotes, but also @

```
string myArgument = @"D:\Visual Studio Projects\ProjectOnTFS\ProjectOnTFS";
```

Comment: Removed the original draft answer, as it's confusing to have both.

Answer (score 6):

I use the following in most of my apps (if required) to add double quotes at the start and end of a string if there are white spaces.

```
public string AddQuotesIfRequired(string path)
{
    return !string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(path) ? 
        path.Contains(" ") && (!path.StartsWith("\"") && !path.EndsWith("\"")) ? 
            "\"" + path + "\"" : path : 
            string.Empty;
}
```

***Examples..***

```
AddQuotesIfRequired(@"D:\Visual Studio Projects\ProjectOnTFS\ProjectOnTFS");
```

Returns `"D:\Visual Studio Projects\ProjectOnTFS\ProjectOnTFS"`

```
AddQuotesIfRequired(@"C:\Test");
```

Returns `C:\Test`

```
AddQuotesIfRequired(@"""C:\Test Test\Wrap""");
```

Returns `"C:\Test Test\Wrap"`

```
AddQuotesIfRequired(" ");
```

Returns empty string

```
AddQuotesIfRequired(null);
```

Returns empty string

***EDIT***

As per suggestion, changed the name of the function and also added a null reference check.

Added check to see if double quotes already exist at the start and end of string so not to duplicate.

Changed the string check function to `IsNullOrWhiteSpace` to check for white space as well as empty or null, which if so, will return an empty string.

Comment: Good, but I would call it AddQuotesIfRequired and add a null check in begin.

Comment: Also, shouldn't it also check if the string is already wrapped in quotes? Calling this multiple times on it's own result should produce the same string each time.

Answer (score 3):

I realize this is an old thread but for people who see this after me, you can also do:

```
string myArgument="D:\\Visual Studio Projects\\ProjectOnTFS\\ProjectOnTFS"
```

By escaping the back slashes you do not have to use the @ symbol.  Just another alternative.

Comment: Although this is true as I have used this in the past, its much simpler and less time consuming to add a `@` at the start of the string, which indicates a true string. Otherwise you will find yourself wasting time adding back slashes all day.