# Cannot handle Blank Space in Application Folder Path in C#

Tags: c#

```
string app_path_temp = App.App_Path + "\\";

string sourcePath = System.IO.Path.Combine(app_path_temp, "Dump\\SID\\temp\\", filename1);

string destPath = System.IO.Path.Combine(app_path_temp, "Training\\", fileBaseName, "\\", filename1);

File.Copy(sourcePath, destPath, true);
```

When I give set the folder path as **"FolderName1\FolderName2\FolderName3\ApplicationPath"**, the code works just fine. However when the path is like **"Folder Name 1\Folder Name 2..."** it doesn't work.

Shows an error **"Could not find file at** **Folder Name 1\Folder Name 2..."**

Comment: Please refer [handle-spaces-in-file-path](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6521546/how-to-handle-spaces-in-file-path-if-the-folder-contains-the-space)

Comment: the Application Path is implicitly set using the `string app_path_temp = App.App_Path + "\\";` How can I add double quotations to `App.App_Path`?

Comment: try to investigate first by using `Directory.Exists`

Comment: @DebaleenSenguptaVehere  to add double quotes to an item, you use double quotes such as "Sally says ""this is a test"" rather quietly"

Comment: @BugFinder So, you mean **"**App.App_Path**"** when it is assigned to `string app_path_temp`?

Comment: @abdul-wahab that link doesn't explain the case when I want to get the file path at runtime. `App.App_Path` gives me the Folder Path at runtime.

Comment: Take out "\\" in Path.Combine because it will add this for you i.e. change string destPath = System.IO.Path.Combine(app_path_temp, "Training\\", fileBaseName, "\\", filename1); to string destPath = System.IO.Path.Combine(app_path_temp, "Training", fileBaseName, filename1);

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In C# 6, you can apply both $ and @ prefixes to the same string, it means "Interpolate this verbatim string", hope this work for you:

```
string sourcePath = $@"{App.App_Path}\Dump\SID\temp";
string destPath = $@"{App.App_Path}\Training\{fileBaseName}";

// Use Path class to manipulate file and directory paths.
string sourceFile = System.IO.Path.Combine(sourcePath, filename1);
string destFile = System.IO.Path.Combine(destPath, filename1);

File.Copy(sourceFile, destFile, true);
```