# How to put space in path string?

Tags: c#, file, path, spaces

I tried many solutions but I fail.

I know that there is a problem with spaces and I can add `@` or `/"` or `""` (but double quotes in code lead to compiler errors)

This is my code:

```cs
string dirAppData = Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.ApplicationData);
string sciezka = @"Microsoft\Windows\Menu Start\Programs\Startup";
string path = dirAppData + "\\" + sciezka;
System.Diagnostics.Process.Start("explorer.exe", path);  // did not work (wrong path)
string sciezka1 = 
    @"C:\Users\Piotr\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs\Startup";
System.Diagnostics.Process.Start("explorer.exe", sciezka1);  // works
```

How should I write in path that it works in the first case?

Comment: Put quotes around it - " - try either \" or ""

Comment: One path has "menu start" and the other "start menu"...

Comment: Does this answer your question? [how to handle spaces in file path if the folder contains the space?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6521546/how-to-handle-spaces-in-file-path-if-the-folder-contains-the-space)

Comment: I would also suggest using `Path.Combine` when merging paths, at least if you want your code to be portable.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Escape double quotes in a string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14480724/escape-double-quotes-in-a-string)

Comment: Thank You. I was mistake with Menu Start and Start Menu.

Answer (score 0):

it's just an typp :D

the first path is wrong.

```
string sciezka = @"Microsoft\Windows\Menu Start\Programs\Startup";
```

it should be

```
string sciezka = @"Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs\Startup";
```

regards